# 2 dataframes save to a file with multiple worksheets

Tags: python-3.x, export, export-to-excel

I have a dataset of country and city data in the same file

I read the file, group and create a country level table and city level table.

Now I am trying to save my results into excel file with 2 worksheets and here is the code i am using but city data table is overwriting my country level data. What am i missing

```
split_country = country['country'].unique()
for value in split_country:
    country1 = country[country['country']== value]
    outputfile = str(value)+'.xlsx'
    country1.to_excel(outputfile, sheet_name='Country', index=False)
    city1 = city[city['country']==value]
    city1.to_excel(outputfile, sheet_name = 'City', index=False)
```

Comment: It seems like your code would overwrite the initial outputfile.  To append a second (or more) sheet consider appending by starting an instance of pd.ExcelWriter with mode='a'. See in docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Answer (score 1):

this code solved the problem

```
import xlsxwriter
split_country = country['Country'].unique()
for value in split_country:
    country1 = country[country['Country']== value]
    outputfile = pd.ExcelWriter(str(value)+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    country1.to_excel(outputfile, sheet_name='Country', index=False)
    city1 = city[city['Country']==value]
    city1.to_excel(outputfile, sheet_name = 'City', index=False)
    outputfile.save()
```